# Override replace module tpl file

Tags: overriding, prestashop

I can't override a template module tpl on prestashop. I have put my new tpl file in theme/module, try in override prestashop folder, no work. Clear cache no change.

Comment: Please check link might get help stackoverflow.com/a/54457507/2769372

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To override a module tpl you have to copy the folder structure and the file you want to override into your theme.

For example if you want to modify the **front.tpl** of the module **modulename** and you have a theme called **yourthemename**

you will have to copy:

`/modules/modulename/views/templates/hook/front.tpl`

to

`/themes/yourthemename/modules/modulename/views/templates/hook/front.tpl`

Note that the folders may vary but you have to keep the structure.

Once the file is copied you can edit it and it will replace the contents of the tpl

Answer (score 0):

Template overrides for PS Modules (for 1.6 and 1.7) belong in the `themes/[YOUR_THEME]/modules/` directory.

Now depending on the module you're trying to override, you might, or might not, need to create additional subdirectories like `views/templates/front` or `views/templates/hook`. Just look at the location of the original module tpl file to get the exact path.